# next-i18next Trans component <a>[Object object]</a> instead of proper link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

I got some error with interpolation in Trans component in next-i18next.
Instead of proper link I get [Object object].
When I check the translation value in React Developers Tools I see that everything is ok.

Here is my usage of this component:
`<Trans>{translation.key}</Trans>`

translation.key is already translated value with html tags in it.
I tried many solutions but every time give me [Object object]

I tried literally each solution on stackoverflow but every time I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The error with `{translation.key}` returning [object Object] is caused because you're returning also the `<a>` tag, creating a React Node (or [object Object]).

To solve the problem do not return the anchor tag directly inside the key.